How To "Fly" A Special Call Sign
I want to know how to mention a special call sign in my CQ.
Today, September 3, 2024 is Merchant Navy Day https://forums.qrz.com/index.php?threads/merchant-navy-day-special-event-gb0mnd.924652/.
Their special call is GB0MND. How do I incorporate this into my CQ?

What you ask is contradictory:

CQ is for soliciting anyone who can hear you.
GB0MND is the callsign you should call for if you want to participate in the event.

So I think what you mean to ask is: "how do I call the special event station?" And the answer is:
"Calling GB0MND from octopusgrabbus" though I recommend substituting your actual call sign for octopusgrabbus to increase 1) chance of response and 2) likelihood of regulatory compliance in your locale.
